# toggle button isnt being set correctly

Tags: sharedpreferences, togglebutton

I think i can simplify the problem domain. Basically i have set the preference activity to have button set to on. The problem arises when i click off and then come back to the preference and its still on i tried to create a boolean switch but form some reason it doesnt work. The code is posted below.

**solution**
I think the solution is to fix the problem of when the user clicks on the toggle button and turns it off since I have set clickable to true in the public void Oncreate method. Every time the user goes back to the preference activity the value is set to on. I think a condition which overrides that parameter would fix my problem.

```
prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, 0 );

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

if (twitter.isChecked() == true)
{
    onoffTwitter = true;
    editor.putBoolean(TWITTER_KEY, true);
    onoffTwitter = true;
}

if (twitter.isChecked() == false)
{
    onoffTwitter = false;
    editor.putBoolean(TWITTER_KEY, false);

    onoffTwitter = false;
}

Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
               "was the twitter checked" + twitter.isChecked(), 
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

editor.commit();
```

And this code is from another activity which hides the button.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, 0);
buttonStatus = prefs.getBoolean(TWITTER_KEY, false); 
Log.e(LOGS, "What is the value for the twitter feed" + buttonStatus);

Toast.makeText(AndroidGUIActivity.this,
               " What is the value for the twitter feed" + buttonStatus,
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

if (buttonStatus==false) twitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I believe I can fix this by setting the initial value of the togglebutton in the xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was not passing the preference value to the twitter but so it wasn't storing the value.

```
prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, 0 );
         buttonStatus = prefs.getBoolean(TWITTER_KEY, true); 
         Log.e(LOGS, "What is the value for the timer feed" + buttonStatus);


        twitter.setChecked(buttonStatus);
```